# How to create IF Statements in Visualforce email template?

Tags: visualforce, email, community, visualforce-component

Hi I have create the Visualforce email template and i have attach the pdf file,in that pdf file name has been Certificate .pdf, but the file name a particular parent name Eg: Mecca Bingo it will show email out upon the pdf file name merging the Four filed name.

I have create the IF statement in email template but it has been show the error.

```
<messaging:attachment filename="{!relatedTo.Site__r.AM_UPRN__c}-
{!relatedTo.Site__r.ShippingCity}-{!relatedTo.Visit__r.Service_Type__c}-{!relatedTo.Date__c}" 
renderAs="pdf">
```

this is my merged file name but  i have tried for if statement

```
<messaging:attachment filename="{!If(relatedTo.Site__r.Name='Mecca Bingo',
relatedTo.Site__r.AM_UPRN__c,'Certificate.pdf')}" renderAs="pdf">
```

It was working nice but i need check the second one merged fields check the if statement i have tried it was occure the error

```
{!relatedTo.Site__r.AM_UPRN__c}-
{!relatedTo.Site__r.ShippingCity}-{!relatedTo.Visit__r.Service_Type__c}-{!relatedTo.Date__c}
```

But I need to check in this format to IF statement

```
<messaging:attachment filename="{!If(relatedTo.Site__r.Name='Mecca Bingo',
({!relatedTo.Site__r.AM_UPRN__c}-
{!relatedTo.Site__r.ShippingCity}-
{!relatedTo.Visit__r.Service_Type__c}-
{!relatedTo.Date__c}),'Certificate.pdf')}" renderAs="pdf">
```

Please anyone kow let me know...

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Unless you use the {} button (or manually indent by 4 spaces) characters like < and > are not escaped so Visualforce markup renders badly. Best to use {} on all Apex and Visualforce - I've don it for you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<messaging:attachment filename="{!If(relatedTo.Site__r.Name='Mecca Bingo',
(relatedTo.Site__r.AM_UPRN__c-
relatedTo.Site__r.ShippingCity-
relatedTo.Visit__r.Service_Type__c-
relatedTo.Date__c),'Certificate.pdf')}" renderAs="pdf">
```

Comment: Hi.. thanks for ur answer and Replay. i have done the IF Statement. in this format.  
                                     
Thanks for ur Priceless Post.. :)

Answer (score 0):

The "Visualforce Function" docs provide examples for their functions.  Check out the `IF` and `CASE` functions.

https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_variables_functions.htm